# How do I do "Authenticating Your Client with Google"?

Tags: android, xamarin, keytool, google-authentication, google-authenticator

How do I Authenticating Your Client correctly with google?
 I'm following this tutorial 
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth

I copy this text into my command prompt -

keytool -exportcert -list -v \
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%.android\debug.keystore

I get this message back "-alias is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

What am doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The copied command shouldn't contain the backslash after -v and it must be placed in one single line, like this:

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

Besides you have to change the %USERPROFILE% location in the command to the path where the .android directory located. (Maybe it is here: C:\User\YourUserName\ , but you have to check it if it's there)

Answer (score 3):

set your cmd path to jdk then run this cmd
WINDOWS
keytool -list -v -keystore %USERPROFILE%/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

MAC/LINUX
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

Answer (score 3):

I think the end goal is to generate the SHA1 key.

Best Alternative is to follow following steps:

1. In Android Studio, click on gradle on the right side panel.

[image]

2. And then navigate to app > Tasks > android > signingReport.
3. Double clicking it will generate the SHA1 key.

Answer (score 1):

best way to get your SHAI is

keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\username\ .android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android