# keytools -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore (for windows)

Tags: android

**Debug Signing Certificate SHA-1**

I run a android project and I want to connect my project to firebase.

To do that I need the sha 1 key. for that reason I have to run this code in my terminal.

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

Lot of people use [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34187555/how-do-i-do-authenticating-your-client-with-google) to to that.

in my case its not working in my computer.

How I just run this commend in my computer.
I use windows 10 and android 3.5

[This is the screen shot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HlMJ.png)

It will be more helpful if someone see my [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/sushen/and-nd-firebase).
:

I also see a approach in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609442/how-to-get-the-sha-1-fingerprint-certificate-in-android-studio-for-debug-mode) but I just want to run this commend in my computer.

Comment: On the rightmost there is Gradle then **Gradle>YourApplication>app>Tasks>android>signingReport**. It will give you SHA1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First set `Path` in the `Environment Variable`

```
E.g C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\bin <Map Your JDK path>
```

Then run your command.

**Or you can do it with the following way.**

You can generate in `Android Studio`

Find Gradle in the top right corner.

Doble clicks on SigningReport.

[image]

You will find it in the console.

[image]

Comment: I see that approach but can I run this commend in my computer.

Comment: @SushenBiswas Updated Answer. You have to Set path first in environment variable then run command,

Comment: See this for more information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211919/errorkeytool-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-p

Comment: I didn't find java in my PC but my android studio running smoothly how can it possible.

Comment: Yes because Java is come up with Android Studio. But you can install standalone JDK. You can download from here. https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Comment: if i do that and set environment variable then Can I run this commend.

Comment: Android Studio comes with prebuild with JDK. Do not need to configure the path on Environment variable

Comment: @Chirag Savsani  Yes I want to run the commend. Now I am Downloading JDK.

Comment: This post is very enlightening and that will be my answer. Thank you @ChiragSavsani

Comment: Welcome. Always happy to help.

Comment: @ChiragSavsani WHen I type this commend in my commend line :
C:\Users\user>where keytool

Its give me that error: 
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).

Here is the Screenshot:
https://snipboard.io/31vfMH.jpg